# Gitlab SSH Authentication Succeeds but still cannot clone repo

Tags: github, ssh

I am trying to clone a git repo over ssh. I have looked at other questions and done research but still cannot get this to work.

I followed the directions here: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

And here: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/error-permission-denied-publickey

I registered the private key with `ssh-agent`, I verified the fingerprint of the public key on Gitlab. I restarted my computer and `ssh-agent` is running.

Executing `ssh -T git@github.com` on Powershell gives the following:
`Hi <username>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`

However, when attempting to clone with the ssh link from github, I get the following:

```
Warning: Permanently added the ECDSA host key for IP address 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX' to the list of known hosts.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

All users on the target directory have Full Control rights.

I'm not sure where to go from here. This is some of the output from running `ssh -vT git@github.com`

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.4.3
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.112.4] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\***/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\***/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\***/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\***/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\***/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\***/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\***/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\***/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\***/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\***/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\***/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\***/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\***/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\***/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-6732d282
debug1: compat_banner: no match: babeld-6732d282
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen C:\\Users\\***/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
```

I know the `-1` means those files don't exist. Was I supposed to name my public/private key pair with a particular name? Do I need to update my PATH variable somehow? Are the `No such file or directory` messages something that needs to be fixed? I don't have an ssh config file, do I need one and what should go in it?

These are questions I haven't been able to find answers to. If someone could offer some insight here, that would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: One potential problem here is that git may be using a different ssh binary than the one you're using from the command line, and might not be compatible with your ssh-agent.  Try putting the private key in the appropriately named file that it suggests.

Comment: I think you're on to something here. I finally got it working, but only by starting over (deleting all keys and the .ssh directory) and using the default filenames. I'm not sure why this made a difference, I think it may have something to do with Step #2 listed here: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/error-permission-denied-publickey#make-sure-you-have-a-key-that-is-being-used  I was tempted to post this as the answer, but since I can't offer much insight, I'll leave it to someone else :/

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue here. It seems this is an issue with Windows, when I use WSL it works fine, so I discard a bad configuration of the SSH keys and the agent.

***TL/DR:*** I did so many things so I don't know what exactly works. But I think this is a direct issue with the command prompt (CMD) on Windows. When I try to clone a repo using PowerShell it works fine, so I'd say to try this first.

This is what I do at the end to make it works:

1. I recreate all the SSH Keys again, updating the public one in GitHub.
2. Delete the current keys on the ssh-agent
3. When I try to add the new private key it says something about UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE.
4. I change the permission attributes (equivalent to `chmod 600`) with `icacls C:\path_to_file\github_key_rsa /inheritance:r /grant:r "%USERNAME%:R"`
5. Added the new private key using `ssh-add` (No errors now)
6. Test the connection with `ssh -T git@github.com` it works fine.
7. I tested with CMD and I got the same error, but when I try it again with PowerShell I was able to clone the repo.